# Easiest way to get the root domain of a website

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to get the "http://www.mydomain.com" portion of my website in code instead of having to change it manually between my development and production servers. I'm sure this is really simple, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Context.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

is what you're looking for.  If you don't have direct access to Context, you can instantiate it at HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host